# How to call part of one method in another in the same class?

Tags: java, rest, methods, overriding

I would like to use part of one method in another in the same class in order not to duplicate several lines in my code.
The first method is:

```
protected UserDTO map(UserEntity entity) {
    var result = new UserDTO();
    var userRoles = entity.getRoles().stream()
            .map(RoleEntity::getId)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    result.setId(entity.getId().toString());
    result.setLastAccessDate(entity.getLastAccessDate());
    result.setRoles(userRoles);
    if (entity.getEmail() != null) {
        var email = new UserDTO.Email(entity.getEmail(), EMAIL_TYPE);
        result.setEmails(List.of(email));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The second one is:

```
 public UserResource updateUser(String id, UserResource updatedUser) {
        var optionalUser = userRepository.findById(Integer.valueOf(updatedUser.getUserName()));
            updatedUser.setRoles(optionalUser.get().getRoles()
                    .stream()
                    .map(RoleEntity::getId)
                    .map(String::valueOf)
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            updatedUser.setLastAccessDate(optionalUser.get().getLastAccessDate());
        var entity = mapToUserEntity(updatedUser);
        userRepository.save(entity);
        return updatedUser;
    }
```

So, I have duplicate code in both methods:

```
.getRoles()
.stream()
.map(RoleEntity::getId)
.map(String::valueOf)
.collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Could you give me the piece of advice - how can I simplify this without creating additional method which will be called in two methods above?

Comment: you don't. You extract that part in (yet) another method, and call it on both places you need it

Comment: Why don’t you want to create another method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a new method. Add it to the `UserEntity` class and call it something like `getRoleIds()`. Then it technically won't be an additional method call since you're replacing the existing call to getRoles.

Ex:

```
var userRoles = entity.getRoles().stream()
            .map(RoleEntity::getId)
            .map(String::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

becomes

```
var userRoles = entity.getRoleIds();
```